# Linear combinations with restrictions on coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand why all linear combinations of two linearly independent vectors $u, v \in \Bbb R^2$ represent the entire plane, but I'm having difficulty interpreting the case where different restrictions are placed on the coefficients. For example, the general form of a linear combination is given below

$$ c \cdot u + d \cdot v $$

where $c, d \in \Bbb R$

Now what happens if we impose the restriction $c + d = 1$? I believe this will represent a line, but I don't understand why.

As another example consider the diagram below

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

According to my textbook, you can fill in the dashed triangle with the following two restrictions

$1.) \hspace{2mm} c, d, e \geq 0$

$2.) \hspace{2mm} c + d + e = 1$

But again, I'm not sure why

**Question: Why does the restriction $c + d = 1$ generate a line and the other two restrictions fill the dashed triangle?**

Any other notes on interpreting restrictions on coefficients would also be appreciated

Comment: This question is far too broad. You could give restrictions that will make the valid linear combinations any subset of the vector space.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the question more focused? I'd be happy if I could understand why the restriction $c + d = 1$ creates a line and the other restrictions fill the triangle

Comment: That would be a perfectly acceptable question, and I might even answer it (possibly).

Comment: Sounds good, I've changed the question

Comment: This is called a *convex combination*.  If $x,y$ are points then $z = ty + (1-t)x$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, is a line segment that starts $(t=0)$ at $x$ and ends $(t=1)$ at $y$.  You can also think of it as weighted sum, where $t$ represents how much weight to put on $y$.  If $t=1$, all the weight is put on $y$, so $z = y$.  If $t=0$, all the weight is put on $x$, so $z = x$.  If $z = 1/2$, then $z$ is exactly half-way between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Similarly, a convex combination of three vectors gets you somewhere between the three.  If you have vectors $w,x,y$ and $z = aw + bx + cy$, $a + b + c \leq 1$, $ a,b,c \geq 0$ then $a,b,c$ tell you how similar you are to $w,x,y$.  So $.8w + .1x + .1y$ is going to be very close to $w$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the restriction $c+d=1$, rewrite this as
$$cu+(1-c)v=v+c(u-v)$$
 For $0\leq c$ this is a ray starting at $v$ and pointing towards $u$, as when $c=0$ the value is $v$ and we translate the vector in the direction of $u-v$ $1$ unit until we reach $u$, then continue to infinity. For $c<0$ we have a ray pointing in the opposite direction.

For the restriction $c,d,e\geq 0$, $c+d+e=1$, write this as

$$cu+dv+(1-c-d)w=w+c(u-w)+d(v-w)$$
Intuitively this is the same, but we are translating in two directions starting at $w$, fanning out in one direction towards $u$ and another towards $v$. Ranging over arbitrary positive values of $c,d$ this is the area in the plane through $w$ spanned by $u-w,v-w$ between the two rays from $w$ to $u$ and $w$ to $v$. We obviously do not get this entire area because $c+d\leq 1$. Because of this condition there is symmetry here. We can rewrite it as
$$v+c(u-v)+e(w-v)$$
and
$$u+d(v-u)+e(w-u)$$
Thus the area is in fact the triangle enclosed by the three lines through the points in the unique plane containing them (assuming nondegeneracy).

Answer (score 1):

the condition $c+d=1$ is easy.
take $$\vec{x}=c\vec{u}+d\vec{v}$$
now substitute $d\to1-c$, you obtain:
$$
\vec{x}=c(\vec{u}-\vec{v})+\vec{v}\longrightarrow\lambda\,\vec{v_0}+\vec{v_1} \textrm{ (vectorial line equation)}
$$
if you vary $c$ continously you obtain a line.
for the other one you should look into Convex Combination (the explanation is longer and a rather tedious one).